# react-native fontvariant small-caps with custom font

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I am building an app that requires Times New Roman or an equivalent.  I have found that a style with `fontVariant: ['small-caps']` has no effect.  Are there specific fonts that have this capability?  Is there a better way to specify this with the font?  I am loading fonts with

```
await Font.loadAsync({
  'times': require('./assets/fonts/TimesRoman.ttf'),
})
```

I have also tried the same with `styled-components` but does not work with this custom font.

Testing on simulator via `react-native run-ios`

Thanks to all,

Comment: For those loading custom fonts through expo, I believe some font styling including fontWeight won't affect custom fonts. You would have to download the bold version of the font, TimesRomanBold.ttf, or whatever it is called. Here's what they say ["Note: Fonts loaded through Expo don't currently support the fontWeight or fontStyle properties -- you will need to load those variations of the font and specify them by name, as we have done here with bold."](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts)

Comment: For those trying to use fontVariant on an android app, If I'm reading [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props.html#fontvariant) right, it's not possible as it's only available on ios.